# Why my sticky sidebar is leaving blank space from top of sidebar?

Tags: javascript, css, sidebar, sticky

It does leaves a blank space from top of it's content and till the sidebar while sidebar still sticks to the left while scrolling.

```js
let sidebar = document.getElementsByClassName("blog-sidebar")[0];
let sidebar_content = document.getElementsByClassName("content-wrapper")[0];


window.onscroll = () =>{
  let scrollTop = window.scrollY;
  let viewportHeight = window.innerHeight;
  let contentHeight = sidebar_content.getBoundingClientRect().height;
  let sidebarTop = sidebar.getBoundingClientRect().top + window.pageYOffset;


  if(scrollTop >= contentHeight - viewportHeight + sidebarTop){
    sidebar_content.style.transform = `translateY(-${contentHeight - viewportHeight + sidebarTop}px)`;
    sidebar_content.style.position = "fixed";
  }
  else{
    sidebar_content.style.transform = "";
    sidebar_content.style.position = "";
  }
}
```

```css
.blog-sidebar .content-wrapper .sidebar-bookmark{
    display: none;
    float:left;
}

.bookmark-list{
        left:0px;
    top:0px;
}
.bookmark ul{
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
}
.blog-sidebar .bookmark-list{
    width: calc(14vw + 30px);
        max-width: 215px;
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
}

.sidebar-bookmark ul{
    display: block;
    list-style: none;
    margin-block-start: 1em;
    margin-block-end: 1em;
    margin-inline-start: 0px;
    margin-inline-end: 0px;
    padding-inline-start: 40px;
}

.bookmark-list a{
    display: block;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 500;
    line-height: 1.6;
    color: #93A1B0;
    border-bottom: none;
    padding-left: 36px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    transition-timing-function: ease-in-out
}
.blog-sidebar .content-wrapper a{
    border:none;
}

.blog-sidebar .content-wrapper a:hover{
    color:#4b5968;
    transition: all 0.15s ease-in-out
}

.bookmark .bookmark-list > a{
    text-decoration: none;
}
@media (min-width: 1200px){
  .blog-sidebar .content-wrapper .sidebar-bookmark {
    display: block;
  }
  .blog-single-simple .right-bar .post-content{
    margin-top:-90px;
  }
  .blog-single .right-bar .post-content{
    margin-top:-110px;
  }
  #blog-single-cection{
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
  }
}
@media (max-height: 710px){
  .blog-sidebar .bookmark-list a{
      margin-bottom: 15px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="blog-sidebar bookmark left-bar">
  <div class="content-wrapper">
    <ul class="sidebar-bookmark bookmark-list ">
      <li>
        <a href="#prerequisites">What are the prerequisites to become a part of fashion industry?</a>
        <ul class="sub-bookmark">
          <li>
            <a href="#fashionStylist">Fashion Stylist</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#merchandiser">Merchandiser</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#fashionDesigner">Fashion Designer</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#textileDesigner">Textile Designer</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#graphicDesigner">Graphic Designer</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#creativeDirector">Creative Director</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#technicalDesigner">Technical Designer
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#qualityAssurance">Quality Assurance</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#productionManager">Production Manager</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#coaching">MAD school : Coaching & Training center</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Also I would like to ask how I can put the effect of smooth scrolling becz it's not working as i expected while clicking on tabs of sidebar

Comment: _"This above html comes under division-bar section"_ - that's vague and ambiguous. Do not make us _guess_ what your actual markup might look like, but present a proper [mre] of your issue.

Comment: If you  run the snippet noting really shows at all as it stands now.

Answer (score -1):

It seems like you are trying to create a sidebar with a fixed position that sticks to the left while scrolling, and you also want to add smooth scrolling when clicking on the sidebar links. To achieve this, you can make a few modifications to your existing code:

1. Add the `position: fixed` CSS property to the `.blog-sidebar` class to keep the sidebar fixed while scrolling.
2. Modify the `window.onscroll` event to update the sidebar's position correctly.
3. Add smooth scrolling to the sidebar links by using the `scroll-behavior` CSS property.

Here's the updated code:

HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <!-- Add your CSS link here -->
</head>
<body>
  <div class="blog-sidebar bookmark left-bar">
    <div class="content-wrapper">
      <!-- Your sidebar content here -->
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="main-content">
    <!-- Your main content here -->
  </div>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS (styles.css):

```css
/* Your existing CSS styles here */
.blog-sidebar {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: calc(14vw + 30px);
  max-width: 215px;
  /* Add other styling properties as needed */
}

/* Add this to enable smooth scrolling */
html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
```

JavaScript (script.js):

```js
let sidebar = document.querySelector(".blog-sidebar");
let sidebar_content = document.querySelector(".content-wrapper");

window.onscroll = () => {
  let scrollTop = window.scrollY;
  let viewportHeight = window.innerHeight;
  let contentHeight = sidebar_content.getBoundingClientRect().height;
  let sidebarTop = sidebar.getBoundingClientRect().top + window.pageYOffset;

  if (scrollTop >= contentHeight - viewportHeight + sidebarTop) {
    sidebar_content.style.transform = `translateY(-${contentHeight - viewportHeight + sidebarTop}px)`;
    sidebar_content.style.position = "fixed";
  } else {
    sidebar_content.style.transform = "";
    sidebar_content.style.position = "";
  }
};
```

Make sure to link your CSS and JS files in your HTML. With these changes, your sidebar should stick to the left while scrolling, and the links should have smooth scrolling effects when clicked.